# Is there an event dispatching/listening concept in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been learning a laravel framework and it has a very interesting implementation of dispatching and listening to events.

I've worked with electron before which has a similar system but it wasn't nearly as good.

Is there an equivalent in the react world? I only know about `addEventListner` but that's a javascript thing and it listens to event happing on the dom, where as I am looking for something like this.

```php
// in the feed component
#[On('tweet-created')]
public function fetchTweets()
{
    $this->tweets = Tweet::with('user')
        ->latest()
        ->get();
}
```

```php
// in the CreateTweet component, dispatched when a new tweet is created
$this->dispatch('tweet-created');
```

Comment: Everything in React is a JavaScript thing. You can emit and listen to arbitrary events; there are many implementations.

Comment: State and Prop changes are the most common events in React. You don’t have to program anything, React updates automatically. Hence the name “React” !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded that react state and specifically tools like Redux and UseContext are React's event system, but in my experience it doesn't come close to the way it's handled in the livewire framework I am trying at the moment.